# Python: Matching a string to list item?

Tags: python

```
cords = []

for y in range(10):
    for x in range(10):
        cords.append((x, y))

print cords
print cords[11]

user_x=raw_input("X: ")
user_y=raw_input("Y: ")

xy = "("+user_x+", "+user_y+")"
print xy


if xy in cords:
        print "Found Match"
```

My question is, why doesn't it print "Found Match", when given 1 and 1 or any other match?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a string will never be equal to a tuple.

```
xy = (int(user_x), int(user_y))
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't run the code, but it looks like:

> xy = "("+user_x+", "+user_y+")"

is a string like so:

> "(3, 2)"

Your list is a list of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Because `"("+user_x+", "+user_y+")"` results in a string, and your `cords` list contains tuples of integers.

Instead of constructing a string you should just be putting the x and y values in a tuple like so:

`xy = (user_x, user_y)`

Or even just:

```
if (user_x, user_y) in cords:
    print "Found Match"
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Well, there are at least two issues here that I can see.

Firstly, the co-ordinates are integers when they're created. `raw_input` returns a string.

Secondly, `xy` is a string, and the co-ordinates are tuples.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> type(xy)
<type 'str'>
>>> type(cords[11])
<type 'tuple'>
```